# Set min-width to swiper slides on a particular breakpoint

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to set a `min-width` in pixel to swiper slides on big screens (width greater than 1200px) only, has anyone already tried/done this? When I set a `min-width` to `.swiper-slide` then the (default) active slide is not properly centered. I tried to set `slidesPerView` to `'auto'` with the `min-width` then I have only 1 full width slide as active, the other ones seem to be out of the viewport.

```
.swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    min-width: 400px;
  }
  
const customerSlider = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 32,
    slidesOffsetBefore: 0,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    loop: true,
    breakpoints: {
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
      },
      1200: {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
      },
    },
  })
```